# Why can't I validate Google Analytic tracking code on subdomain

Tags: google-analytics

I have a subdomain, http://m.abc.com. On the Google Analytic account, I defined a property for the subdomain. The tracking code was copied and pasted on the subdomain files.

On Google Analytics reporting, we need the Demographics info. I've added the code to generate the report:
[image]

But when I click Validate Code, the validation does not proceed. All I get is the page below:
[image]

I've gone over the instructions and am certain that I did not miss out any item. I've also turn on the Enable Advertiser Features and Enable Demographics and Interest Reports.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: click Skip Validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It typically takes at least 48 hours for the displayFeatures to validate (at least it took that long for me). If even after 48 (or even 72) hours it's still not validating, then you can skip that step without detriment.

Comment: The Enable Advertiser Features and Enable Demographics/ Interest Reports were set to on yesterday. That means I may need to wait up to tomorrow (or the day after). If in the event, it's still not validating, then I'll skip. Thanks